# Checkboxes and onItemClick in ListView populated from database

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` populated from a database. How can I have checkboxes and `onItemClick` at the same time?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, dataarray);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: need to use custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below links you can get some idea about that..

http://fundoocode.net/android-listview-checkbox-example-onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener/

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

[Android ListView With CheckBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030131/android-listview-with-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

hope this is useful to load listview with check box http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html