# Set RadioButton for Custom Adapter and GridView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview

I have a project in which i wanted to set my custom `View`, not simple `Android GridView`.
I did that, now i want to set `RadioButton` for each row.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647001/listview-with-custom-adapter-containing-checkboxes)

But i could not specify the Boolean Array in this Reply.
Here is my Code.
First `Items Layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_x="12dp"
        android:layout_y="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_x="157dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"></RadioGroup>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_x="302dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:checked="false" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And simple `GridView` with a `Button`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".DisplayActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="387dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:background="#abc"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Adapter Class :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import  android.widget.RadioButton;

public class CarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Car> {
    RadioButton radioButton;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    ArrayList<Boolean> booleans = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList, ArrayList<Boolean> mlist) {
    super(context, resource, carArrayList);
    this.booleans = mlist;
}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Car car = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_car, parent, false);
        }
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        radioButton = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        TextView carName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView carSIM = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        carName.setText(car.getName());
        carSIM.setText(car.getSIM());

        return convertView;

    }
    RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            booleans.set((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked); // get the tag so we know the row and store the status
        }
    };

}
```

I tried this in `getView` Method :

```
    radioButton.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    radioButton.setChecked(booleans.get(position));
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener);
```

And `mListener` is :

```
    RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        booleans.set((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked); // get the tag so we know the row and store the status
    }
};
```

But it gives me

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at line `radioButton.setChecked(booleans.get(position));`
```

Here is `Main Activity` :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {
    CarAdapter carAdapter;
    Car car;
    Car car2;
    ArrayList<Car> carArrayList;
    GridView gridView;
    Button test;
    ArrayList<Boolean> booleans;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        carArrayList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        car = new Car("Davie", "Smith");
        car2 = new Car("Enrique", "Wall");
        carArrayList.add(car);
        carArrayList.add(car2);
         booleans = new ArrayList<Boolean>(carArrayList.size());
        carAdapter = new CarAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, carArrayList, booleans);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(carAdapter);
        test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (gridView.isItemChecked(gridView.getCheckedItemPosition())) {
                String name = (carAdapter.getItem(gridView.getCheckedItemPosition())).getName();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here is " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is not true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CarAdapter modify this...

```
public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList, ArrayList<Boolean> mlist) {
        super(context, resource, carArrayList);
        mlist = this.booleans;
    }
```

to

```
public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList, ArrayList<Boolean> mlist) {
        super(context, resource, carArrayList);
        this.booleans= mlist ;
    }
```

Comment: No, this is not the reason.
I dont know why i wrote that in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `booleans` ArrayList  to `mlist` ArrayList which can be  **empty** and so you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`..you have to assign `mlist` to  `booleans` ArrayList

```
mlist = this.booleans;
```

should be..

```
this.booleans = mlist;
```

in your `CarAdapter` constructor.

Comment: No, this is not the reason.
I dont know why i wrote that in this way.

Comment: if your `booleans` is it will not get `booleans.get(position)`

Comment: what do u mean exactly?
I did not understand.

Comment: as you initialize `boolean`, it is empty.now as you are passing `mList` (with value in it) to constructor, there it should be assign to `boolean` as above so `boolean` should get all value contain in your `mList` but you are assigning `boolean`(empty) to `mList` so when you fetching position it do not get position ans throw Exception..

Comment: Sir. 
I did this in my code :
this.booleans = mlist;

And i did this in my main Activity : 
    ArrayList<Boolean> boolArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
and then pass it to my Adapter.
But still that exeption.
Should i do something when declare it ?

Comment: I did it.
I have change assignment of boolean array in constructor.
and size of this to empty.

Comment: where you adding data to `booleans`

Comment: according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) `getView` will give you array data set you passing to constructor which is `carArrayList` here..try get `carArrayList` position text to String  and check whether still you get exception?

Comment: i change the constructor to this : 
public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Car> carArrayList, boolean[] booleans) 
i made a boolean array instead of arralyList of boolean.
Now it works. but i can choose all of them and also when i click the radioBotton , it doest select the row i want in girdView.
I insert a button  in main activity and did this in its onClickListener : 
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here is " + carAdapter.getItem(gridView.getCheckedItemPosition())).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: But before putting radioButton, when i selected a row , the Toast displayed the name i clicked in the exact row,
Now i want when the row is selected, or radio button, the Toas method work.
I mean i would like it returns the selected item in custom adapter and gridview.

Comment: please modify the above code it is very difficult to understand your problem in comment..

Comment: Look, i edit the constructor and change the forth argumant from ArrayList<Boolean> to boolean[] booleans.
Now it run without error, but i can choose multi items of rows and when i check a radio button of a row, the whole row does not select.
and the others code you see is in test.onClickListener which is in the question.
My question is how can link the radio button to the row of grid view with single choice mode.

Comment: by row you mean single cell of gridview or all horizontal cells of gridview.

Comment: I mean every single row of the gridView.
For example, when we set the android standard gridView to single choice mode, it allow us to select one horizontal row at time.
I want something like that, but with my adapter.

Comment: I can not chat, because im new in stackoverflow.
Ok, i will post a photo.