# null value on variable passed from inside a onclick response

Tags: java, android, encapsulation

Is there any reason why method CreatePlan won't allow me access to variable recipe_name from the onRecipeClicked function which is retrieved from the recyclerview adapter. The Log shows that the value is retrieved from the recyclerview, but I can't seem to pass it to another method.
Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
Also is there a way of assigning the auto incremented id created from createPlanRecipe to the id variable in createPlan?

```
public class CreateMealPlan extends MainActivity {

    DatePicker datepicker;
    Button submit;
    List<com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Category> listRecipe = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c;
    RecyclerView recipeList;
    RecipeListAdapter adapterRecipe;
    String recipe_name;
    EditText editPlanName;
    Integer id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_meal_plan);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        Intent a = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        break;
                    case R.id.recipes:
                        Intent b = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this,RecipeSearch.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        break;
                    /*case R.id.shoppingList:
                        Intent c = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this, ShoppingList.class);
                        startActivity(c);
                        break;*/
                    case R.id.mealPlan:
                        Intent d = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this, MenuPlan.class);
                        startActivity(d);
                        break;
                    /*case R.id.reminder:
                        Intent e = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this, Reminder.class);
                        startActivity(e);
                        break*/
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        datepicker = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        ListRecipes();
        RecipeListAdapter.OnRecipeClickListener listener = new RecipeListAdapter.OnRecipeClickListener() {
            public void onRecipeClicked(int position, String recipe_name) {
                Log.d("Recipe selected",  recipe_name);
            }

        };
        adapterRecipe = new RecipeListAdapter(this, listRecipe, listener);
        recipeList = findViewById(R.id.recipes);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recipeList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recipeList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recipeList.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create);

        // perform click event on submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CreatePlan();

            }

            });
    }
    public void ListRecipes() {
        listRecipe.clear();
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String selectQuery = " SELECT recipe_name, image, image2, category" + " FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_RECIPE + "  GROUP BY recipe_name";
        c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        Log.d("Query", selectQuery);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Category category = new com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Category();
                category.setRecipe_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("recipe_name")));
                category.setImage(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("image")));
                category.setImage2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image2")));
                category.setCategory_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category")));
                listRecipe.add(category);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

    }
    public void CreatePlan(){
        editPlanName = findViewById(R.id.editPlanName);
        String plan_name = editPlanName.getText().toString();
        DatabaseManager db;
        int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = datepicker.getMonth();
        int year = datepicker.getYear();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        Integer d_name = day;
        Log.d("Date", String.valueOf(d_name));
        String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d_name);
        String date = day + "/" + month + "/" +year;
        db = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
        db.createPlanRecipe(d_name, dayOfTheWeek, recipe_name);
        db.createPlan(plan_name, id);

    }


}
```

Comment: Greetings! - it looks like in the `Create_Plan` method, you are accessing the *global* `recipe_name`, but you have ambiguity on the click event because the *passed variable* has the same exact name so doesn't look like your global one is initialized or changed.

Comment: If I don’t declare a global variable it doesn’t identify recipe_name in the CreatePlan method at all.

Comment: Yes - true. But you have two things named `recipe_name`. The event listener also has an attribute with the same name that it is using. So the first thing to do is to remove the variable `recipe_name` that is being passed in the `onRecipeClicked` event listener -> it is interfering with the global variable. The listener doesn't have an event to capture the value clicked and assign it to the global `recipe_name`. Once added, you would be changing the global variable and then it won't be a null value anymore.

Comment: So I need to add an event to assign global recipe_name the value passed from the listener? How would I do that I’m really confused.

Comment: Yes! Now I haven't done event listeners and adapters in a while, but [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647001/listview-with-custom-adapter-containing-checkboxes) should work for you. Notice the arguments passed on the check event method